# Detecting Dark Mode on web apps

Tags: google-chrome, themes, youtube

Is there a way to make web apps like YouTube detect system dark mode automatically on Ubuntu 20.04?

Edit: Some web apps can fallow system theme on windows. If you have dark mode enabled then these apps will be displayed using a dark theme. In Ubuntu 20.04 when i configure this apps(YouTube on google chrome) to fallow system theme it will still display light theme even if I have Ubuntu on Dark mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a problem between Ubuntu and Chrome, in this page, you can see which theme the system is using.
https://codepen.io/alisterlf/full/LYbvwER

This page works on ubuntu with firefox, but not in chrome.
In windows, this page also works with chrome, so that's why I think it's a problem between Ubuntu and Chrome.

This is a known issue that is traceable thru [this page](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903).

Comment: I'm not sure this works out of the box. At Firefox 98.0.1 under Kubuntu 20.04, that's definitely not the case. I don't use Fx anymore, just opened the installed one to test. Are you sure there isn't a setting under Fx to enable that?

Comment: Is this still unresolved? I'm having this exact same issue still.

Comment: Can we do something like hardcoding the system theme for chrome till the issue is not resolved at the root?

Comment: I don't want to use chrme://flags because it shows an experimental feature warning

Comment: This issue was fix in july of 2023

Answer (score 2):

If you switch Google Chrome to GTK theme (Settings->Appearance->Themes), the Chrome browser appearance changes with the system theme. However, this does not change the browser theme setting, as you can see in @Alister's link: https://codepen.io/alisterlf/full/LYbvwER

As a result, the system theme does not propagate to websites that allow you to use the system theme. This is a known issue, and is being tracked [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903). Toggling Chrome to use the GTK theme seems like the "right" way to do this, and hopefully when this issue is fixed, you will be able to use Youtube's "use device theme" setting (Profile Pic -> Appearance -> Use Device Theme).

Answer (score 1):

For me, adding flags that force dark theme helped

```bsh
/usr/bin/chromium %U --enable-features=WebUIDarkMode --force-dark-mode
```

You can also change this command in you chromium app details panel
[image]
Then choose Application
[image]
And put the command I have listed at the beginning of my answer into **Command:** field

System info:

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.15.40-1-lts
- DE: Plasma 5.24.5

Comment: I too, use jetbrains mono as system ui font. Everything is both consistent and beautiful with this open font. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the source of the web app (or site) then you can use `matchMedia` from Javascript:

```
if (window.matchMedia && window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches) {
    // dark mode
}
```

As a bonus, if you want the app to update if the OS changes from one mode to the other, you can watch for changes:

```
window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').addEventListener('change', e => {
    const newColorScheme = e.matches ? "dark" : "light";
});
```

Otherwise, there is no option that I’m aware of that will force an application to comply with the colour scheme or mode of the host OS